# Finding unique combinations of consecutive numbers within an array

Tags: java, numbers

So I have an array that has been sorted, for example [1,2,3,8,9,10] or [1,1,2,2,3,3] or [1,3,4,5,6,7] and I want to find unique combinations of 3+ consecutive numbers. So that could be in the examples above (1,2,3) and (8,9,10), or (1,2,3)(1,2,3)(1,2,3), or (3,4,5,6,7).

So I've written something that would work for two consecutive numbers but I'm not sure how I'd search for 5 consecutive numbers, then 4 consecutive numbers and then 3. Also how would you deal with numbers that are the same.

Would a recursion work here?

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        for (int j = i+1; j<5; j++) {
            if (array[i] == array[j] - 1) {
                score++;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: you want to find how many times this consecutive numbers are repeated? or just array has consecutive series or not?

Comment: Just that if the array has 3+ consecutive numbers. It could 2 sets of them or 1 set of 4 consecutive numbers or 1 set of 5.

Comment: Can you explain how you get (1,2,3)(1,2,3)(1,2,3) from [1,1,2,2,3,3]?

Answer (score 0):

This will work if there are no repeated digits:

```
static List<List<Integer>> seqCombos(List<Integer> a)
{
  List<List<Integer>> seqs = new ArrayList<>();
  for(int j=0, i=1; i<=a.size(); i++)
  {
    if(i == a.size() || a.get(i)-1 != a.get(i-1))
    {
      if(i - j >= 3) 
        seqs.add(a.subList(j, i));
      j = i;
    }
  }
  return seqs;
}
```

Test:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{    
  Integer[][] tests = 
    {
      {1, 2, 3, 8, 9, 10},
      {1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7},
    };

  for(Integer[] test : tests)
  {
    System.out.println(Arrays.asList(test));
    List<List<Integer>> seqs = seqCombos(Arrays.asList(test));
    for(List<Integer> seq : seqs) 
      System.out.println(seq);
    System.out.println();
  }
}
```

Output:

```
[1, 2, 3, 8, 9, 10]
[1, 2, 3]
[8, 9, 10]

[1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
[3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
```

If there are repeated digits then things get a lot more complicated. I'm not even clear what the rule is, as I don't see how you get (1,2,3)(1,2,3)(1,2,3) from [1,1,2,2,3,3]?